# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [Test] associated with context path [/TestStruts]. - [unknown location]

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, action-mapping

I'm trying my first application on struts 2.3.16 in NetBeans 7.2.1. It shows the following error on entering a URL - `http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/Test.action` (There is a `Test.jsp` page).

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /TestStruts/Test.action
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [Test] associated with context path [/TestStruts]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**The `Test.jsp` page:**

```
<s:form namespace="/TestStruts" action="test">
    <table border="0" class="">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <s:textfield id="name" name="name" label="Enter your name"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <s:textfield id="email" name="email" label="Enter your email"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><s:submit value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>            

</s:form>
```

**The action class:**

```
package actions;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("name = "+name);
        System.out.println("email = "+email);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**The `strtus.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">


<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="myapp" />

    <package name="test" namespace="/TestStruts" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="test" class="actions.TestAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/Test.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**The `web.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In addition to jar files of Spring, I have added the following jar files to the classpath.

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-chain-1.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-digester-2.0.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
- commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.19.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.16.jar
- struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.16.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.16.jar

---

When the URL is changed to `.jsp` from `.action` like `http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/Test.jsp`, it shows the following warnings.

```
Dec 22, 2013 9:00:44 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'test' in namespace: '/TestStruts'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Dec 22, 2013 9:00:45 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'test' in namespace: '/TestStruts'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `/TestStruts` is a context path at which deployed your application. It has the same path as namespace in your package. Try

```
http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/TestStruts/test.action
```

When URls is rendering from the struts tags it's trying to find a corresponding action configuration. If there's no config found the warning is issued.

Comment: I have tried this URL - `http://localhost:8080/TestStruts/TestStruts/test.action` but it gave this warning `WARNING: Could not find action or result: /TestStruts/TestStruts/test.action
There is no Action mapped for action name test. - [unknown location]` preventing the page from being displayed.

Comment: Change this `<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">`

Comment: Changed it but no luck. Is there any library I might be missing?

Comment: Where's your `struts.xml` location?

Comment: It is under `WEB-INF`, `WEB-INF/struts.xml`.

Comment: You should move it in the source folder.

Comment: I have moved `struts.xml` to the `src/conf` folder - `src/conf/struts.xml` but unfortunately, it did not make a difference.

Comment: `src` is location, source root folder, it should be on classpath, the struts is able to locate it.

Comment: It worked, when I created a folder named `classes` under `WEB-INF` and moved the `struts.xml` file under that location, `WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml` as mentioned in [this](http://niitbhopal.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-create-struts2-project-in.html) blog about struts applications in NetBeans. Thank you very much for your time and effort. (I do not have votes today. I will do it right tomorrow).

Comment: Thank you very much @Tiny for sharing that solution. I had to move the file to WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

After executing the app, leave the console and put the URL link (like http://localhost:8080/yourprojectname/.jsp) with your index page and run it.
It would be running fine.