# Handle a not action mapping in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, action-mapping

I have a problem, i have implemented the  in struts2, and its going well, but when i put in the browser, an action that does not exists, like

http:mysite/someurl/somefake.action

i have a screen, where you can read "Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [Portaaasdasdl] associated with context path [].
"

the question is:

how can i know when i have a no mapped action and redirect that to a jsp where i can tell that action is not valid, or redirect to a custom jsp with a mesage "PAGE NOT FOUND"

i can't solve, and im a little frustrated.

Comment: A little search over questions of this site be enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20730967/573032

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12795634/1700321 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/16293143/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** In `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/file_not_found_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

**Step 2:** In Web Content Folder create `file_not_found_404.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      PAGE NOT FOUND
   </body>
 </html>
```

**Note :** *I have not checked but I think this will work only for `Apache tomcate 6`.*

Comment: thanks, but option one is not working, i dont know why, the problem was solved with <default-action-ref />  tag

Comment: yes. you are right. But what I suggested is for both actions and jsp pagenames in url. If someone put jsp name in url than we can make a custom error page. In your case <default-action-ref/> sounds good for actions.